# Open window, navigate through it

Tags: php

I know this is possible in Perl, but I was wondering if this can be done in PHP.

What I want to do is open a browser with a window, click to a link in that page, or navigate in the browser, then it has a simple textbox called test, and I want to put text in that box then click submit and all done in PHP. I know jQuery and Javascript so I am fine if part of this little project should be done in any of those two. I did some research on it and couldn't find a clear approach to this.

I don't need written code provided for me, I just need an answer with suggestions and if possible, little codes to do some tricks.

Thanks in advance.

-G

Comment: PHPUnit appears to have [Selenium bindings](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/selenium.html) which should make that possible … but the feature is marked as "Partially implemented" and I don't have any personal experience with it. I'd stick to Perl for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is a server-side language so everything gets done on the server and the result sent back to the user to be displayed in the browser. You can't do things like this in PHP. Your best bet is to use javascript to click links and submit forms on the page... but mind explaining what this is for so we can maybe provide a way of doing that?

To do this in Javascript you can use jQuery's [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) to click links and [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) to submit a form. Since the form is on the second page, the submit code would have to be on that page as well. If you really want to automate this, you can load the first page in an iFrame and work with stuff inside but both pages (the parent and iframe) have to be on the same domain. To bypass that, I'd write a Chrome extension that inserts a small content script in those pages with my JS (the click/submit stuff).

In PHP you can download the first page, parse the link you want clicked out of it, then download that page, figure out the form that's on it and them use cURL to submit that form. You can use cURL to download the pages as well. Here's a tutorial on how to [get the contents of remote files using php](http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/php-tutorial/reading-a-remote-file-using-php.aspx).

Comment: PHP is a programming language. It is most commonly used as a server side language for web programming, but it does have legs beyond that.

Comment: You can use PHP-Cli to make PHP another interpreted language for the Linux console, so your statement is not true, @sachleen, it can be used outside the "server-side scripting" domain. Even shell-script in PHP is possible!

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. I use PHP CLI for a few things for myself. But from what I got out of the original question, it sounds like Grigor wants this done on the client side and not on the server. I guess that was not the correct interpretation.

Comment: just a challenge to myself. How would this be done in Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can replicate the form post in PHP with curl. Here itself provide the value to the textbox. Navigating window in php is something I am not sure about.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has an extension named `cURL` that's capable of download a web from PHP and access it or save it to disk.

To fill a field in a form, you might previously know the field names and the form action and code it in the request made by cURL.

The documentation is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Hope that helped!